# VBA Pasting values to next column on another Tab

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, and trying to copy values on one sheet (the "lookup" sheet) and past the values in 'next' column on another sheet ("actuals" sheet). There are multiples of each.

I cannot figure out how to paste to the next column each time I run the macro. What currently happens is the first macro, "actualizationautomation Macro" runs (which updates the values correctly) and then it copies correctly, but pastes into the same Column (F) each time I run it.

What I want to do is paste in the column to the right each time.(G, then H, then I, J, K, and so on) Here is what my code looks like (I'm doing this for multiple sheets).

```
    Sub ActualsAutomation()
'
' ActualsAutomation Macro
'

'
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!AllSheets"

    Sheets("SS Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("SS Lookup").Range("F1:F141").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("SS Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("SS Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("SS Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("All Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("All Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("All Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("All Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("All Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Base Specialties Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Base Specialties Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Base Specialties Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Base Specialties Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Base Specialties Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Combat Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Combat Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Combat Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Combat Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Combat Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Great Value Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Great Value Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Great Value Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Great Value Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Great Value Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Persil Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Persil Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Persil Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Persil Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Persil Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Purex Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Purex Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Purex Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Purex Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Purex Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Renuzit Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Renuzit Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Renuzit Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Renuzit Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Renuzit Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Snuggle Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Snuggle Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Snuggle Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Snuggle Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Snuggle Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Sun Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Sun Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Sun Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Sun Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Sun Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Surf Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Surf Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Surf Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Surf Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Surf Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value
End Sub
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You desperately need to read up on how to avoid Select, which is inefficient and usually unnecessary (and the ActiveWindow commands are I guess thrown up by the macro recorder but are superfluous). E.g. this

```
Sheets("All Lookup").Select
Range("F1").Select
Range("F1:F239").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("All Actuals").Select
Range("F3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

can be be replaced with

```
   Sheets("All Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Copy
   Sheets("All Actuals").Range("F3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

or this way, which is more efficient as avoids the clipboard

```
Sheets("All Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("All Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value
```

Tto paste in the next empty column on row 3

```
Dim c As Long

c = Sheets("All Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Sheets("All Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(239).Value = Sheets("All Lookup").Range("F1:F239").Value
```

Looks like you need to loop through sheets, so add a worksheet variable and reference that rather than the actual sheet name above "All Actuals".

Comment: I updated my above code to reflect changes made, and now the Macro is all out of whack. I'm sure I'm making beginner mistakes here. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: It's probably better if you retain your original code in your question so that people can see the initial problem. When you say out of whack, what exactly do you mean? This line `Sheets("SS Actuals").Range("F3:F241").Value = Sheets("SS Lookup").Range("F1:F141").Value` doesn't look right as the two ranges are not the same size.

Comment: I get compile error. and the 2nd "Dim C as Long" is highlighted. What about everything else. Does the code look right to you?

Comment: You only need one `Dim C as Long` line. Haven't looked in detail, nothing else obvious but then I don't know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: My main goal is to copy the data on each of the "lookup" tabs which contains last week's data, (which is always contained in column F, and past the data into the associated "actual" tab, copying the data for each week (The fist week should copy into column F, the next week into Column G, then H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P. and so on). Please let me know if you have any future questions. Thank you!

Comment: Did you make the correction above? Have you done any debugging, stepped through the code to check what is happening?